# Way to stretch image points on SDL?

Tags: c, sdl

I was wondering if there is a way to stretch an image based on its 4 points (as shown in the picture), and if not, how could I achieve that?

[Illustration of what I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PlAj.png)

I've tried SDL_RenderCopyEx, but it seems it only rotates an image.

:)

Comment: If you can use OpenGL, you can just draw a textured quad and adjust the vertex coordinates to stretch it...

Comment: okay, thank you ! I just thought there'd be an easier way to do this : )

Comment: I don't think the SDL rendering functions offer advanced distorsion like this. OpenGL looks like the only way.